# Microsoft Graph API Nest JSON Request is failed

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing App leveraging Microsoft Graph using Python 3.6.

I am getting very strange behavior when requesting Graph API which uses request data as nested JSON.

This is a successful request:

```
url = f "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}"
headers = {
  'Authorization': f 'Bearer {office365_access_token}',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
  "city": "Tokyo"
}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"), headers = headers, method = 'PATCH')
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

The next snipped fails with an `HTTP Error 400` error. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) states that the `skills` property is a String Collection, so I used an Array of String values:

```
url = f "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_principal_name}"
headers = {
  'Authorization': f 'Bearer {office365_access_token}',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
  "skills": ["swift", "python"]
}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"), headers = headers, method = 'PATCH')
urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

The only difference is whether the value is a string or not. I can dump the data dictionary to a JSON string,  so I don't think the code is wrong but I do not know why this error occurres.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a *bug* related with Microsoft Graph itself, specifically with [`User` *update* operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0). For example the following query:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json
{
  "skills": [
    "Fortran",
    "Cobol"
  ],
  "city": "Helsinki"
}
```

indeed *fails* and returns the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The request is currently not supported on the targeted entity set"
    }
}
```

At the same time updating another User properties, for example User.otherMails property which has the same `Collection(Edm.String)` type  as `User.skills`:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json


{
  "otherMails": [
    "office365admin@gmail.com",
    "office365admin@yahoo.com"
  ],
  "city": "Helsinki"
}
```

completes successfully.

**Workaround**

It appears it fails when `skills` property of [`User` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) is getting updated along with another properties.  But if **only** a `skills` property is getting updated

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json

{
  "skills": [
    "Fortran",
    "Cobol",
    "C"
  ]
}
```

no error occurs and the operation successfully completes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But my request is only updating skills property and the request fails.

Comment: @penlight, surprisingly, your example for updating `skills` property only works on  my side